# how to use "components" argument in geopy GoogleV3 geocoder?

Tags: geocoding, geopy

I would like to use GeoPy to geocode a number of locations; I would like to use the GoogleV3 geocoder as it is supposed to allow me to restrict the results so that, for instance, I can specify that I only want to look for Springfield in Illinois and not in any other state. I think the "components" argument should allow me to do this.

However, I have not been able to figure out from the [documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/) what information I need to provide or how. All I have found is:
"components (dict) –
Restricts to an area. Can use any combination of: route, locality, administrative_area, postal_code, country."

Does anyone have an example of how this dictionary should be composed and of how it is called?

Answer (score -1):

```
geocode( s, components = { 'country': 'usa' } )
```

Comment: thank you user3406263.  For anyone else looking for this information and wanting to get down to the level of US states, this seems to work 'geocode( "Gloucester", components = { "administrative_area": "MA" } )'